# ruby on rails Controller class instantiate a ruby class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to RoR .I want my controller to instatiate an existing class from lib .

Collect data in the form of a string and throw the result on the view.erb.Can I do that.

Do i have to create a new model object and that should that model object inturn call the lib class.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you want to do.

If you used a library class - a **module** for example - its automatically instantiated, when you use '`include`'

If you just have a generic **class**, and you included it somewhere, then you already have the class object loaded and can call methods on it. Or you just create an instance manually with '`object = new MyClass`'.
And then call whatever you like on '`object`'.

Whatever Information you collect inside the controller method, you can access in the view, when you place an '@'-Symbol before your variable.
So if you want your **show.html.erb** look like this:

```
<h1>My String:</h1>
<%= @mystring %>
```

then you have to do something like this in your controller:

```
def show
  ...
  @mystring = MyClass.get_my_cool_string
  ...
end
```

Hope that helps...